# can 2 projects create a single dll in MS VS 2008?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Is it possible to create a single dll using 2 projects in MS VS 2008? Please let me know. I am using C and C++ as my programming language. Please provide me with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do this.  The simplest way to structure the project is that

- Project1: Produces a .lib file
- Project2: Produces a .dll which links the .lib from Project1

It's not really possible though to have two projects directly compile into a single DLL without an intermediate step of a .lib file.  It can be done with some vicious double include logic in the project system but it's a solution that's not recommended or really easily maintained.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create one static library from one of them, and one dll from the other one.

Comment: thank you for your response. could you please provide me with an example. thanks